# Serialize JSON in a recursive struct

Tags: json, recursion, struct, hashmap, rust

I have this JSON:

```
{
  "argument0": {
    "argument1": "test",
    "argument2": {
       "argument3": "test3"
    }          
  }
}
```

I need to use some kind of recursive struct with methods like the `HashMap<String, _>` in Rust. The key should always be a `String` but the value can be a `String` or the same `Argument` struct.

```
#[derive(Clone, RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable)]
struct Argument {
    key: String
    value: String Or Argument
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking a question, it's expected that you show us [the research you have done](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This helps understand what you are missing and provide answers. It also helps weed out people who want to use SO as a code-writing service (which it is not). You should [edit] your question to include what you have attempted, why that doesn't work, and then we can go from there.

Comment: Your struct corresponds to a single-linked list, wheras your json object seems to be a tree, so something is wrong. My best advice is that you start out creating the correct data structure before you start worrrying about json. Furthermore try to export to json before you import. Hereis the manual page for exporting to
https://doc.rust-lang.org/num/rustc_serialize/json/index.html
You should probably read up om enums to be able to represent StringOrArgument https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/enums.html

Comment: Thanks Shepmaster, Niesle for the comments. Niesle, i researched about the trees representation in here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21791786/rudimentary-tree-and-pointers-in-rust, thanks for this orientation, now i can redo some coding to see the exported json as you recommended. The representation in json is important because this is for a REST API and i need this exact representation.

Answer (score 6):

You have a few distinct problems here.

First, you want to be able to define a data type that can be either one type or another type, but not both. This is what Rust's [`enum` data type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html) is intended for.

```
enum Value {
    String(String),
    Argument(Argument),
}
```

This `Value` type can contain either a `String` or an `Argument`, but not both.

Now, we need to define the `Argument` type. In your example, an argument can contain arbitrary field names, so we can't just define a `struct`. Instead, we can use a map collection from the standard library to map `String`s to `Value`s, such as [`BTreeMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html). We'll also define a [type alias](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#creating-type-synonyms-with-type-aliases) so that we can use the name `Argument` instead of `BTreeMap<String, Argument>` elsewhere in the program.

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

type Argument = BTreeMap<String, Argument>;
```

Now that we've successfully defined the type, let's define its serialization behavior using the [serde](https://serde.rs/) library. Serde can automatically serialize types from the Rust standard library, and user structs can implement or derive the `Serialize` and `Deserialize` traits to add the functionality to their own types.

For most structs, we can just add a `#[derive(Serialize)]` and/or `#[derive(Deserialize)]` to implement the necessary traits for serialization. In this case, we want to customize the deserialization of our `enum` to be [untagged](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged), so it just emits the value of the enum, not an object with "String" or "Argument" as the key. Instead, we just want the JSON to contain the value. We do this by adding a special attribute to the struct, `#[serde(untagged)]`.

Here's a short Rust program that demonstrates the above concepts. This program will read your JSON example, and print the [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/hello/print/print_debug.html) representation of a Rust type  that represents the data.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive; // 1.0.78
extern crate serde; // 1.0.78
extern crate serde_json; // 1.0.27

use std::collections::BTreeMap;


#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Value {
    String(String),
    Argument(Argument),
}

type Argument = BTreeMap<String, Value>;

fn main() {
    let argument: Argument = serde_json::from_str(
        r#"{
            "argument0": {
                "argument1": "test",
                "argument2": {
                    "argument3": "test3"
                }          
            }
        }"#,
    ).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", argument);
}
```